# JavaFX: Returnable values of Tasks when ran in thread pool using Executor

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, threadpool

I have a `Task` to be executed, and is submitted to a cached thread pool `ExecutorService`. It ran smoothly, but I need to be able to retrieve its returnable value. How could this be done?

Sample code:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnableTask -> {
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnableTask);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    return thread;
});
Button btn = new Button("Run Task");
btn.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
    try {
        Object get = threadPool.submit(new Task<String>() {
            @Override
            protected String call() throws Exception {
                //simulating long-running task
                    Thread.sleep(3_000);
                //return result
                    return "Warren Nocos";
            }
        }).get();
        System.out.println(get);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
});
```

The output is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `onSucceeded()` callback (it will be executed on the JavaFX Application Thread):

```
Button btn = new Button("Run Task");
btn.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
    Task<String> task = new Task<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String call() throws Exception {
            //simulating long-running task
                Thread.sleep(3_000);
            //return result
                return "Warren Nocos";
        }
    };
    task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
        String result = task.getValue();
        System.out.println(result);
    });
    task.setOnFailed(event -> {
        task.getException().printStackTrace();
    });
    threadPool.execute(task);
});
```